# How can I fix Safari iCloud Tabs failing to display in Big Sur?

Tags: icloud, safari, macos

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro, an iPad Air 3rd generation and an iPhone SE 2020. The MacBook Pro doesn't display any iCloud tabs, while the iPad and iPhone both display all open tabs from both the other devices.

I've tried signing out of iCloud on all devices and on just the Mac and signing back in again, and just toggling Safari off and on in the MacBook Pro's iCloud settings. I did the latter three or four times and it did temporarily fix the problem once, but only for about 24 hours. Also, it may be relevant that to switch Safari back on, I have to click the tick the Safari box and agree to merging data *twice* instead of once.

Comment: How are you trying to view the icloud tabs on the mac?  How long are you waiting for the sync between devices to happen after you turn on Safari in the iCloud settings?

Comment: @fsb 1) Using the iCloud tabs button and the tabs overview page. 2) Between toggling Safari in iCloud off and on, I've waited between a few seconds or minutes and several days.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it correctly (99% of the time here, the person is doing it wrong so that's why I asked).  You've also done all the steps I would've recommended, too. I'll keep researching but I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: @fsb Much appreciated. I'll probably call Apple Support about this one so will share the solution if I get to see what steps are involved.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, at least most of the time. I guess it might be down to using a flaky internet connection (down for a few minutes every 50 minutes or so). I'll leave the question up in case others encounter the same problem.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add that info as an answer.  It will help people who search for 'questions that have answers'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may have fixed itself, or been fixed by Apple. It might be due to using a flaky internet connection (ours typically goes down for a few minutes every 50 minutes or so). I'll do some further tests over the Christmas period to see if the problem recurs.